# Using igraph for multiple graphs in R

Tags: r, igraph

If let's say, I have graphs named `w1 w2 w3 w4 .............. w100`, and there are a total of 100 graphs like this, and if I want to calculate the `modularity` of these graphs, then is there any way that I can somehow write a function, so that it calculates the modularity of each graph and returns a numeric vector or will we have to manually calculate it for every file ( the way I am doing it right now )?

Code for making graphs I used:

```
wt=read.table("NP7.txt")
wt1=matrix(nrow=nrow(wt), ncol=2)     
wt1=data.frame(wt1)
wt1[,1:2]=wt[,1:2]      
write.table(wt1,"test.txt")
library(igraph)
wt=read.table("test.txt")
wg7 <- graph.edgelist(cbind(as.character(wt$X1), as.character(wt$X2)),
                 directed=F)
sum(clusters(wg7)$csize>2)        
plot(wg7)
```

I have like 100's of files like `NP1.txt NP2.txt ........... NP100.txt` of which I have to make graphs of. And I am currently saving the graphs name as `wg1 wg2 wg3 ............. wg100`.

Comment: You probably should be storing all your graphs in a list. Then you could easily sapply over the list. How are you creating all these objects?

Comment: @MrFlick, all these graphs I have made from different datasets, that I first scanned using `read.table` and then making the graphs.

Comment: Well, you probably should be lapplying over the list of files to read as well. Having a bunch of different variables cluttering up the global environment like that doesn't make much sense. Especially when you want to work on them as related objects.

Comment: @MrFlick, how can I do that? `lapply(bunch of file names)` ?

Comment: As #R's @MrFlick says, you could most definitely be using lapply or another *apply function. I'm trying to write a solution, but if you have any example code to give me graphs to work with that would be very helpful.

Comment: Show the full code you use for one graph.

Comment: @NerdLife, I have actually, 100's of `.txt` files, `NP1.txt NP2.txt NP3.txt ......... NP100.txt` of which I am making graphs of. And then those graphs I have named as `wp1 wp2 wp3 wp4 ....... wp100` whose modularity I have to calculate.

Comment: @jlhoward, updated the post for showing how I am making graphs. :)

Comment: @user3797829 thanks, though I meant like something reproducible that I could run in R (probably with a built it or public data source) to give me an example. It's not a big deal though, we should be able to help you without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it looks like your text files files have edgelists, with no header row. Then this should be pretty close.

```
library(igraph)
files <- paste0("NP",1:100,".txt")
f.mod <- function(file) {
  w <- read.table(file)
  g <- graph.edgelist(cbind(as.character(w$V1),as.character(w$V2)))
  plot(g)
  wtc <- walktrap.community(g)
  return(modularity(wtc))
}
mods <- sapply(files,f.mod)
```

If you need a list of graphs, then do it this way:

```
get.igraph <- function(file) {
  w <- read.table(file)
  g <- graph.edgelist(cbind(as.character(w$V1),as.character(w$V2)))
}
graphs <- lapply(files,get.igraph)
lapply(graphs,plot)
mods   <- sapply(graphs,function(g)modularity(walktrap.community(g)))
```

Comment: Hey! That worked. But, I have two doubts. I don't think it makes a list of graphs which I can see, for example, like I was doing earlier, `plot(wg7)`. Also, I am calculating modularity by doing something like, `wtc <- walktrap.community(wg7)` and then doing `modularity(wtc)`. I think this is doing in some other way.

Comment: Right. I was reflecting what was in your code, which does *not* calculate modularity. See the edits.

Comment: that works perfect. I just wanted to know how can I access the individual graphs? What it does basically right now, is create these graphs, but it just hurries through all the graphs that are being made. How can I access them later on? Example: If I want to see the graph of `NP4.txt`, how can I do that?

Comment: Using the second code block, where `graphs` is a list of the graphs, you can reference the graphs as, e.g. `graphs[[4]]`. Note the use of double-brackets. So `plot(graphs[[4]])`.