# Centrality calculations from multiple TPMs

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

Brain wanted. I don't know if this can be resolved with igraph. Basically:

a.) from my data I would like to create TPM per id (done see the sample code)

b.) I would like to create a directed graph for each TPM

c.) calculate the betweennness of specific nodes (in my example is 1 and 5)

d.) return in a separate file based on id the betweennness of the desired nodes

How can I do this for a large dataset with more than 1000 TPMs?

Some similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24888007/using-igraph-for-multiple-graphs-in-r)

Desired output:

[image]

Data structure:

[image]

Sample code:

```
Transition matrix creation:


lapply(seq_len(nrow(stack)),
       function(i) {
         tmp <- trans.matrix(as.matrix(stack[i, 2:6]))
         write.csv(tmp, file =  paste0(i, ".csv"), quote = FALSE)
       })
```

Outcome TPMs per id, each df represents TPM per id

```
df1<-structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4), `2` = c(1, 0, 0, 0), `3` = c(0, 
1, 0, 0), `4` = c(0, 0, 1, 0), `5` = c(0, 0, 0, 1)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `2` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `3` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `4` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `5` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df2<-structure(list(X1 = c(0, 7, 8, 9), `6` = c(0, 1, 0, 0), `7` = c(0, 
0, 1, 0), `8` = c(0, 0, 0, 1), `9` = c(1, 0, 0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `6` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `7` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `8` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `9` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df3<-structure(list(X1 = c(10, 14, 22, 23), `14` = c(0, 0, 0, 1), 
    `22` = c(1, 0, 0, 0), `23` = c(0, 0, 1, 0), `25` = c(0, 1, 
    0, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(
    X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", "collector"
    )), `14` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `22` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `23` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `25` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df4<-structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 13), `1` = c(0, 0.5, 1), `2` = c(1, 
0, 0), `13` = c(0, 0.5, 0)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `1` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `2` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `13` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))

df5<--structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2), `1` = c(0, 0.333333333333333), `2` = c(1, 
0.333333333333333), `5` = c(0, 0.333333333333333)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `1` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `2` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector")), `5` = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
    "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))



Sample data:

    stack<-structure(list(X1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), a = c(1, 0, 10, 2, 2), 
        b = c(2, 9, 22, 13, 2), c = c(3, 8, 23, 1, 1), d = c(4, 7, 
        14, 2, 2), e = c(5, 6, 25, 1, 5)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
    "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), spec = structure(list(
        cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), a = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), b = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), c = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), d = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector")), e = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
        "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
        "collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Sample data

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding Thanks stacks gives the TPMs based on this I need the graphs, and betweennness

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding stack is a data frame columns that represent the measurement of the values of the data frame. The values themselves I am after. The stack importance is in the id that there are several different measurement as well.

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding thanks, df1,df2, df3, df4, df5 were created based on stack data using the sample code. They rerepsent the TPM based on id. After that, the TPM was introduced in another software that eas udes to calculate the betweennesss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible `igraph` option

```
# interested vertices in all graphs
v <- c("1", "5")
data.frame(
    t(
        list2DF(
            lapply(
                # get all `df`s in the global environment and save in a list
                mget(ls(pattern = "^df\\d+")),
                function(x) {
                    # row-column indices for non-zero values
                    inds <- data.frame(which(as.matrix(x[-1]) != 0, arr.ind = TRUE))
                    # replace values in `inds` by row or col names
                    df <- transform(
                        inds,
                        row = x$X1[row],
                        col = names(x[-1])[col]
                    )
                    # create graph object
                    g <- graph_from_data_frame(df)
                    # if the interested vertex shows up in the graph, then we calculate its betweenness centrality; otherwise, return NA
                    sapply(v, function(z) {
                        if (z %in% names(V(g))) {
                            betweenness(g, z, normalized = TRUE)
                        } else {
                            NA
                        }
                    })
                }
            )
        )
    ),
    check.names = FALSE
)
```

gives

```
      1  2
df1 0.0  0
df2  NA NA
df3  NA NA
df4 0.5 NA
df5 0.0  0
```

Comment: g thanks when you havetime could you please add some commdnts/explanations.

Comment: @user11418708 I added comments.

Comment: many thanks for your time as I see igraph doesnt consider decimal values such as 0.5. Can this be adjusted? Df4 more specifically

Comment: many thanks again when you have time could you please update the 'betweenness(g, z)' line with 'betweenness(g, z, normalised = T)'

Comment: many thanks for your time - some more question is there a way to order the results in decreasing order? For example, if I read into more than 11 df the order would be df1 df11 df2 df3...and not df1 df2 df3...I tried to add the order function with less success

Comment: @user11418708 With `NA`s in the output, could you show the desired output with reordering? If it is just a question of reordering rows by columns, perhaps you can create a new post with more information and ping me. I will try to help you there.